# What is the alternative for Apache activemq-broker jar which has support for Jakarta as in JDK 17 and Spring 6?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, spring-jms, messagebroker

I have an application that is based on Spring 5 and it uses Apache activemq client and broker libraries. We are now migrating to Spring 6 which requires Jakarta namespaces as specified by JDK 17. But, there is no jakarta support in activemq-broker jar. The 5.18.1 release only supports jakarta for the activemq-client. Is there any alternative for the broker library that supports Jakarta? Or is it possible to continue using apache activemq for client and broker with Spring 6?

The only option that I think is possible is find an alternative for the entire apache activemq library that has support for jakarta in both client and broker

Comment: You might consider moving to ActiveMQ Artemis, the next generation broker from ActiveMQ. It has had a Jakarta implementation of both client and server for awhile now and provides a fully functional implementation of JMS 2 & Jakarta Messaging 3.1.

Comment: I don't know why you're being downvoted, this is a good question. Are you using an embedded broker or are you using a network broker?

Comment: @JustinBertram We did consider using the Artemis but waiting for the upgraded version of ActiveMQ seemed to be worthy instead of migrating to Artemis as it would require many changes to the existing derived functionality from ActiveMQ.

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher , Yes we are using an embedded broker, Like Matt Pavlovich mentioned in his answer, we built his PR locally and the functionality is working fine. But, still we would want a release candidate of activemq to use in production

Comment: @hellokk, by "existing derived functionality from ActiveMQ" I assume you mean things which are supported in ActiveMQ "Classic" (either explicitly or implicitly) which are not supported in ActiveMQ Artemis. If that's the case, can you elaborate on what those things are? We're always looking to improve compatibility between the brokers where it makes sense to ease the burden of migration. Thanks!

Comment: @JustinBertram
Most of the functionality are present. But the level of refactoring requires is a overhead.
We are trying to check if artemis can be used. Can it be used as an embedded broker with jakarta support?

Comment: Yes, ActiveMQ Artemis can be used as an embedded broker with Jakarta Messaging support. WildFly has been doing this for several years. You just need to use the `-jakarta` dependencies (e.g. `artemis-jakarta-server`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: Version [6.x](https://activemq.apache.org/activemq-6000000-release), with support for Spring 6.x support and Java 17 has been released at November 2023. Use that version!

---

**Old answer:** The activemq-client-jakarta.jar can be used to connect Jakarta-based applications to a remote broker running ActiveMQ 5.18.1 just fine. There is nothing over-the-wire that causes incompatibility between Jakarta-based ActiveMQ clients and javax.jms-based ActiveMQ broker.

The only time you need a Jakarta-based broker with Spring 6 is if you used embedded broker in your application or unit test.

Apache ActiveMQ is planning the 5.19.x series to support Jakarta. As of this post, there are only a few minor clean-ups needed before the PR will be merged.

If you need an early release, you can build a SNAPSHOT build from this PR and the Jakarta-based ActiveMQ broker works.

ref: https://github.com/apache/activemq/pull/996